# Call into newtype constructor

Tags: haskell

I have a newtype `Env` defined like this:

```
newtype Env a = Env (State (Context Type) a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState (Context Type))
```

I want it to be automatically coerced into places where `State (Context Type) is expected` with no runtime cost, but instead I get this error:

```
flip evalState ctx $ Env <$> compile expr
```

Assuming compile is of the correct type, 
`compile :: a -> Env a`

This is the error:

```
Data constructor not in scope:
      Env :: Env Expr -> State (Context Type) c
```

Sure, data constructors are different than newtype constructors, but how can I make `evalState` accept the `Env a`?

Comment: You either have a typo, or there's more than one file and `Env` is not being exported. Can you give more details about how your program is organized?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia compile and Env are imported from another module but I don’t see how that would affect the result. You can change all types to Int to remove unknowns like Context Type and Expr but the error would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message means that the **data** constructor `Env` is not getting imported (as opposed to the **type** constructor `Env`). This has nothing to do with the difference between `data` and `newtype`.

```
data    Env = Env (...)   -- Same terminology
newtype Env = Env (...)   -- for both
     -- ^     ^
     -- |     data constructor
     -- type constructor
```

Check your import statements (are they qualified? Do they use explicit import lists?), and your export lists. In particular, this is a common point of confusion:

```
-- data constructor hidden
module Bar (Env, ...) where   -- only exports the type constructor

-- data constructor exported
module Bar (Env(Env), ...) where
-- or --
module Bar (Env(..), ...) where   -- these do export both the type and data constructor Env
```

Then, once `Env` is in scope, you will still get a type error, because `Env` has type `State (Context Type) a -> Env a` but it is being applied to an `Expr` (assuming that's the type of `expr`). You need to deconstruct `Env` instead:

```
runEnv :: Env a -> State (Context Type) a
runEnv (Env f) = f

-- or, in the definition of Env

newtype Env a = Env { runEnv :: State (Context Type) a } deriving ...
```

So you can write

```
flip evalState ctx (runEnv (compile expr))
```

If you're defining `runEnv` explicitly as a function, you could also refactor `evalState` into it:

```
runEnv :: Context Type -> Env a -> a
runEnv ctx (Env f) = evalState f ctx

---

runEnv ctx (compile expr) :: Expr
```

Comment: I see, I forgot to deconstruct Env but I thought I didn’t have to do it and it will be magically coerced because of newtype. Would it be better if I made Env a type alias for State (Context Type), since then I don’t need to deconstruct Env. So use type instead of newtype.

Comment: You could do that too!

Comment: Nothing gets magically co-erced. One the code is *compiled*, the distinction between `Env` and `State (Context Type)` is erased (which means, I think, there is no overhead in calling `runEnv`), but you still need to distinguish them in order for compilation to succeed.